# Conditional independence given a conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, independence

Let $Y_1,\dots,Y_d, Z$ be random vectors such that $(Y_1,\dots, Y_d)$ is conditionally independent given $Z$. Does it then hold that $(Y_2,\dots, Y_d)$ is conditionally independent given $E[Z|Y_1]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Let $Y_2, \dots, Y_d$ be conditionally independent given $Z$, but not independent.  Let $Y_1$ be a constant.  Then $(Y_1, \dots, Y_d)$ are also conditionally independent given $Z$.  But $E[Z|Y_1]$ is a constant, so asking for $(Y_2, \dots, Y_d)$ to be conditionally independent given $E[Z|Y_1]$ is the same as asking for them to be (unconditionally) independent, which does not hold.